# Limiting file access for a huge number of users

Tags: server, users, services, user-management

The ubuntu is really great for it's user management, every service can use it's own system user: but should I use it for distribution?

Let's say I have a service, that I host, with many customers who only should be able to access it's own files, should I use the ubuntu users? What if the number of ubuntu users is reaching billions?
Can I restrict file access for the users in another way? Virtual Users?

My plan is just to limit the file access for each of "my customers". They should be able to start processes running on my server who should not be able modify the system or other user files. The server must *of course* be secure. I know I can limit file access to each ubuntu user - but should I really use ubuntu-users?

Let's say I am hosting an apache server to customers - Then the users can upload executable files, maybe designed to make bad things to my system, and those files should be executed as their user with limited file access. Or if I host something else and they can execute other types of files.

How do a proceed? Should I user the built-in ubuntu users or should a use something else?

Comment: Do you want this done per group of users or per user?

Comment: And you don't want each user to modify other files? Also, do you want users to be able to globally access and/or edit files?

Comment: per user, every user has it's own private files

Comment: exactly no one should be able to change someone else files. They should  only be able to edit/read it's own files. They can also start processes who also just should be able to access the user files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via UNIX permissions, and already exists as based in Ubuntu.

Home folders can do this already. Each user, as you know, has a home folder. They (and the superuser) are the only ones who can read files in there.

Processes start with the same permission set as the user. For example, a execuatable containing `rm -rf /etc/` will only successfully run if that user has permission to write directly to /etc. However, you should note that system files NEED to be read by all users. You can't change that without SERIOUS problems.

Comment: Thank you, but maybe if the users are growing to billions, is it a great solution? Are the ubuntu users designed to be that many? Why must every user be able to read system files?

Comment: Ubuntu in theory can handle infinite users. System files contain coed configuration info, and all users (or the programs they run) must be able to read this data for various purposes. Note that this does not mean they can write. They can't. That would be stupid. Also, you realize there are 7 billion people in the world, right? At least 14% of the world will be using ONE PC?

Comment: No, I was not very clear, sorry. If I host services to users in the world. They should not be able to upload executable files to make bad things.

Comment: They can't do bad things. Not unless you give them the permission to do so. Also, to do worldwide hosting, you should have an entire army of PCs doing the work for you. Then things get much more complicated (networking, linking, datacenter administration, etc). For 1m users, you would need at least 1000 servers. Being as big as gmail requires at least 475k servers